# I want calculate user touch's point area

Tags: ios, touch, coordinate

I want to check the area of User's touch using touch.location()

how can i divide circe with equal 10 parts and user detect area of touch's position

[image]

if user touch that area then i want display "1" at label

(image have 4 pieces but I want 10 pieces)

Answer (score 0):

Following example divide a view's touch area into sectors like cutting pizzas pieces. The view's center point is considered as an original point of the coordinate. Then we calculate the radians of the line between touch point and center point to find out which piece it's in.

```
class ExampleView: UIView {

    let numberOfPieces = 10

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        let touch = touches.first
        if let location = touch?.location(in: self) {

            let centerPoint = CGPoint(x:self.bounds.midX,y:self.bounds.midY)
            let radians = atan2(location.y - centerPoint.y,location.x - centerPoint.x)
            var degrees = radians * (180.0 / CGFloat.pi) + 180.0 // adding 180 for making the first piece at left side.
            degrees = (degrees > 0.0 ? degrees : (360 + degrees))

            let piece = Int(degrees / (360.0 / CGFloat(numberOfPieces))) + 1
            print("piece \(piece) touched.")
        }
    }
}
```

The default UIView's coordinate system is:

```
       270  
180             0  
       90
```

So we add 180 degree to rotate it to:

```
      90
0            180
      270
```

Then the first piece is at left side as needed in the diagram.

Comment: how can i get touched area if i want 10 equal area instead of 4 area

Comment: How do you divide the area? First row 5, second row 5?